# Symfony, Twig :can not assign current datetime to input with class js-datetimepicker

Tags: symfony, twig, datetimepicker

In a Symfony project, I use js-datetimepicker class to datetime input field to pick a datetime. It works fine (I can pick datetime). 
My problem is that I can not assign the current datetime to this input field, By the way, I can directly display current datetime on screen!

When I inspect the HTML page in the browser, I see this warning: 
        The specified value "{{ \"now\"|date(\"d/m/Y h:m\") }}" does not conform to the required format. The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

I tried, even, the indicated format: "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm", but it does not work as well!

My code is like this:

- My Controller:

  ```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
      ->add('datestart', DateTimeType::class, [
              'widget' => 'single_text',
              'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datetimepicker',
                         'format' => 'd/m/Y h:m']
          ])
      ->add('dateend', DateTimeType::class, [
              'widget' => 'single_text',
              'attr' => ['class' => 'js-datetimepicker',
                         'format' => 'd/m/Y h:m']
          ])
      ->add('ok', SubmitType::class)
      ->getForm();
      $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
  {
    /* ... my action ... */
  }
  return $this->render('AppBundle:Stat:period.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'type' => $type
  ));
  ```
- My Twig template:

  ```
   Date & Time: {{ "now"|date("d/m/Y H:m") }}    

  {{ form_widget(form.datestart, {'attr': {   'class': 'form-control', 
                                              'value': '2018-01-01T00:00',   
                                        }
                               }
                ) 
  }}


  {{ form_widget(form.dateend, {  'attr': {
                                  'class': 'form-control ', 
                                  'value': '{{ "now"|date("d/m/Y h:m") }}', 
                               }
                                          }
                 ) 
  }}
  ```
- The display of current datetime, at the top of template, works fine.
- The static assign for datestart works fine!
- But the assign of current datetime to dateend does not work at all !!  (I tried also this format: {{ "now"|date("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm") }} but got the same result!

[Here is my rendering:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRiJA.png)

Any help please ?

Comment: can you show your js code in the template for the datetime-picker ?

Comment: Did you try to set html5 to false in your form type ?https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#html5

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In fact, I discovered, throw the conversations related to the tuto I used, that it does not support integration of time. I found though a link, expected to ensure that [link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Now I'm still trying to use it .. there are some requirements I'm installing... Yes I tried set html to false...but does not work for sames reasons..

Comment: I finally, could implement the datetimepicker correctly using the above link, but discovered also what was inhibating all my action: there have been a portion of code, in some place of my base template, outside the head balise,  reimplementing an other version of bootstrap and jQuery: wich is :  {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  {% endblock %}.

Comment: when I removed this portion, every thing went well. But, I still need a click on the datetimepicker to get the current time... thanks very well